# Problem installing Mac OS X Lion on Mac Mini

Tags: macos, install, mac-mini

I am installing Mac OS X Lion on a Mac Mini (c2d, 2GB RAM). The installation goes fine, until it rebooted. After rebooting, it shows the following screen for almost 3 hours. The  progress bar does not indicate any remaining time.

Should I continue this or cancel the setup?

[image: After rebooting]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have anything important on the box. I would reboot into Recovery Mode try installing Lion again.

If that fails then erase the hard-drive (back up any stuff you need to), and try to install Lion again on a clean drive. It should not hang for 3 hours plus on the install.

Answer (score 0):

If you can go back into Recovery mode, you may wish to:

- Open up the Terminal and see if you can find the installer logs to see what went wrong.
- Use Disk Utility to verify the S.M.A.R.T. status of the volume and otherwise check the volume for defects.

Answer (score 0):

I just struggled with this same problem from the App store download to upgrade my mid-2007 Mac Mini.  I tried a lot of things, but the one that worked was to reboot with the Snow Leopard install CD in the drive.

I had given up and decided to just wipe the drive and reinstall Snow Leopard and then upgrade from that clean install.  Once I rebooted (with the Option key down), the screen shown above reappeared.  I groaned, and then it went to the next install screen, saying 34 minutes remaining.

Fingers crossed.